# mysql select query with adding new field as TimeIN TimeOUT

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table name as attdata with 2 field EMPID, attDate

| EMPID | attDate |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023/05/23 08.30 |
| 101 | 2023/05/23 19.30 |
| 203 | 2023/05/23 08.30 |
| 203 | 2023/05/23 17.31 |

How to query get select data one month record, each employee ID each day record should be display as below.

| EMPID | TimeIN | TimeOUT | OT Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023/05/23 08.30 | 2023/05/23 19.30 | 120 |
| 203 | 2023/05/23 08.30 | 2023/05/23 17.31 | 1 |

after 9 hours of work, the next hours should be overtime in minutes.
if a duplicate record is available each day TimeOUT field should be Maximum ending time.

[attdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpQl9.png)

I need to query records from the table with the new field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the `group by` and the aggregate functions `min()` and `max()` to get time in and out. and `TIMESTAMPDIFF` to calucalate the overtime :

```
select emp_id as 'EMP ID', min(attDate) as 'Time IN', max(attDate) as 'Time OUT', 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(attDate),  max(attDate)) - 9*60 as 'OT Minutes'
from mytable
group by emp_id
```

Result :

| EMP ID | Time IN | Time OUT | OT Minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023-05-23 08:30:00 | 2023-05-23 19:30:00 | 120 |
| 103 | 2023-05-23 08:30:00 | 2023-05-23 17:31:00 | 1 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/QlQe780R)

Comment: great thank you, and same time could you please tell me how to convert mysql format this attdata. 3/8/2017 08:30 to 2017-03-08 08:30

Comment: Glad to hear :) try this : `select STR_TO_DATE('3/8/2017 08:30','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i');`

Comment: `select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('3/8/2017 08:30','%d/%m/%Y %h:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i')` if you want to get rid of seconds

Comment: Dear @SelVazi its display each employee 1 record only, i want to see all data. if add where clause where date(attDate) between date('2017-01-01') and date('2017-01-31')

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://dbfiddle.uk/VoQthLbd

Comment: Yes This is perfect, please tell if employee missed to punch timeOUT (i mean no attdate timeout data on that day TimeOUT field should be empty.. how to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253748/discussion-between-mafaz-and-selvazi).

Comment: You probably need to ask an other question for this use case